# How to add an alias subdomain with SSL support in Google Apps

Tags: google-app-engine, ssl, https, dns, alias

I have the domain hosted under Google apps. Suppose it is example.com with their ssl certificate uploaded and working properly. Now I added a domain alias example2.com
It seems DNS resolves it ok.

Now I like to upload a new certificate related to example2.com domain, but I obtain the error message *The SSL certificate references subdomain outside of managed domains*
Then I'm unable to upload the certificate for the alias domain

My objective is our customers can access to the website either using original url https://example.com or the alias https://example2.com

Is there some limitation to add SSL certificates to be applied to a domain alias?

Answer (score 1):

This process is a real PITA. Right now (but probably not for very long) you add SSL certs using Google apps, under advanced, security. You upload your cert as a p12 and pem file, then you can assign that certificate to a matching alias domain.

My guess is your SSL cert doesn't match your domain alias, you should use OpenSSL to dump the info and check it does.

You also need to have verified the domain ownership in Google apps first.

Usually the cert upload will fail if it's the wrong info, but you could also try packaging your key and certificates(including intermediate) again.

As a side note, you will not be able to map a naked domain to appengine, this is not supported - it will have to be a sub domain e.g www.example2.com

Answer (score -1):

I think I found where the problem comes from: I'm using an App Engine app, and it is mapped to a custom domain, but only the main domain can be linked to SSL certificate, secondary domains cannot be SSL secured. This is what I found.